# best way to select data from one table or another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two temporary tables, say `#t1` and `#t2` in Sql Server 2008. I need to create `#t3` such as:

- when `#t1` has rows, indifferently of `#t2`'s contents, `#t3` = `select * from #t1`
- when `#t1` has no rows, `#t3` = `select * from #t2`

we can assume `#t1` and `#t2` have the same columns but I don't think I would like to rely on that fact.

I was thinking of something that draws some logic out of '`if exists (select * ...)`' statements, but wouldn't there be better like some sort of bool operators ?

Comment: How would you want to treat the case when t1 and t2 do not have the same columns?

Comment: @Radu Gheorghiu It doesn't matter since he's using `#temporary table`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to implement the logic as:

```
if (exists (select * from #t1))
begin
    select *
    into #t3
    from #t1;
end;
else
begin
    select *
    into #t3
    from #t2;
end;
```

You can do this in one statement as:

```
select t.*
into #t3
 from ((select *
        from #t1
       )
       union all
       (select *
        from #t2
        where not exists(select * from #t1)
       )
      ) t
```

However, I think the explicit `if` is a clearer way to express your intent.

Comment: +1, but changing the `exists(select * from #t1)` to `exists(select 1 from #t1)` will result in a much better performance, since `1` is the lowest bit that can be read, there's no need to select all the data just to verify if anything exists.

Comment: @EmmanuelRC the optimizer is smart enough to avoid considering the SELECT list, so your comment is wrong. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4115354/904178

Comment: @EfranCobisi Even better

Comment: @Efran Cobisi Thanks for pointing that out, I think that I just come from the old school then, will test that though. lol

Comment: it just seems that both branches are being executed when I try your first example ? I drop #t3 before the if statement, but always get an error in the second branch complaining about #t3 already existing

Comment: yeah, seems like my problem is showcases right there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468290/using-if-else-to-determine-a-select-into-statement

Answer (score 0):

This query would do just that, would see if there are rows in `t1` and in that case populate table `t3` with the contents of `t1`, provided they have the same columns, otherwise it populates `t3` with the contents of `t2`.

```
IF(select count(*) from t1) > 0 
    BEGIN 
        select * into t3 from t1
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        select * into t3 from t2
    END
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85c86/1) so you can see how it works. To test the case when `t1` does not have any rows, just remove the line that inserts into `t1`, rebuild schema and re-run the query.